# create unique node or create unique index

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How do I create unique node in `neo4j`? 
I have model for user, and It has property like `UserID`, `serName`, `EMailID`, `Mobile`, `Address`, `Zipcode` ect...

I want to create unique node for above user. I have `UserID`, `UserName`, `EMailID`, `Mobile` as unique field. so, when same `UserID` or any field mention here is trying to enter again, it should be return as error.

It it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is for the stable version of neo4j(1.9) as 2.0 does change how indexing is presented.

You're saying your `User` Node will have several properties, each unique, will these be used as a composite key, or will just the UserName be used as a Key?

Neo4j has a special class for doing a type of "get or create" node, but it only works on one key, so if you were creating a composite key, you'd have to do something like concatenate yours keys.

Look for the documentation [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/transactions-unique-nodes.html). Here is an example:

```
public Node getOrCreateUserWithUniqueFactory(String username, GraphDatabaseService graphDb) {
    UniqueFactory<Node> factory = new UniqueFactory.UniqueNodeFactory(graphDb, "users") {
        @Override
        protected void initialize(Node createdNode, Map<String, Object> properties) {
            created.setProperty("username", properties.get("username"));
        }
    };

    return factory.getOrCreate("username", username);
}
```

Comment: thanks @Nicholas for your reply. I have some unique properties in my User model (eg. UserID, UserName, EMailID, MobileNo). This fields never be duplicate within my user. so, I can not make it composit key. And one more thing, I am using node.js, so I am looking for javascript code to do this. do you have any idea?

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-unique-indexes.html . REST API so available from javascript.